# tag name in header, delete or howto ..?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have peculiar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490376/angular-datatables-how-to-render-column-with-model-binding). The header is

> Angular Datatables: How to render column with model binding?

but someone insist of removing the first part so it becomes

```
How to render column with model binding?
```

We have now been in a "battle" where I have rolled back two times. The reason behind should be

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/171858

But in my opinion 'Angular Datatables' should persist in the title, because that is what is indexed by for example google. I have extremely successfully knowledge about SEO - so I know what I am talking about. `'Angular Datatables'` in the title will return more precise hits for future stackoverflow users seeking on google for the term "angular datatables render column" as an example.

Who is right in the SO context? Is it fair to remove the overall textual qualifier in the header, just because the question is tagged with something similar named in the listed tags?

Comment: Don't put tags in titles.  If you can naturally work the name of a technology *into* the title, do that.  I wouldn't base your titles on what a search engine *might* look at or *might* miss elsewhere.

Comment: @davidism, I know for a fact that people search like "stackoverlow tag name in header" - to get precise results. If you leave "stackoverflow" out you get a lot of crap, if you leave "stackoverflow" in, you get this page. Try it out yourself. Try search for ["stackoverlow tag name in header"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stackoverlow%20tag%20name%20in%20header) vs ["tag name in header"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tag%20name%20in%20header) ...The same with "angular datatables" ...

Comment: What's "here"? Please add a screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

Rollback wars are never constructive.

While leaving the tag in the title isn't ideal, you could make it blend into the title instead.

> How do I render column with model binding with Angular Datatables?

Comment: Yes, but then it would seem like I want to alter OP's header for some unspoken reason I cannot explain, and why should I do that in the first place?

Comment: @davidkonrad:  There's a clear reason: the title should read better than it does.  If you want the tag in the title, this is the preferred way.

Comment: So why not leave it in front ...?

Comment: The tag in the question already accomplishes what leaving it in front would.  If it can be worked in organically, that's far preferable.  Google already puts the tag in front on occasion when a question is searched for.

Comment: No it is not in a SEO-term. To produce more organic hits you would leave 'angular dataTables <question title>' . It is a fact. I have proofed this to davidism above.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why he doesn't understand that millions of questions don't do `C#: how does async work` or `query: how to use .on()`.  Can lead a horse to water...

Comment: @davidkonrad Tags are indexed by search engines. Citing the question you've linked: "Stack Overflow is optimized so that *tags are indexed by search engines* along with the content of the question". All you have to do is search for "[stackoverflow git undo](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=stackoverflow+git+undo)" to see that the "git" tag is indexed. In fact, the first few results have "git" automatically prefixed in their title.

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto  - see my comment above to  davidism. Proof of concept, case closed. Of course tags are indexed by search engines - that is your name too - but what have most importance in a search engine? I know it is difficult stuff for many people, an many people does not really understand. I should probably never have raised the issue but just fighted my own war for the links I want to have good precense in google.

Comment: @davidkonrad Title of the page *already include first tag* - not sure if it is good for SEO to see "angular angular- how..." Note that there is big difference between links on random site vs. links on well known sites - and SO is later one. I.e. it may worth for search engine to actually optimize for SO search results explicitly (like Bing - https://www.bing.com/search?q=csc+command+line+return+code) or quite possibly to do it implicitly (but no one would really know/tell).