# Can/should we stop questions from starting with a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, title

The [advice on tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) is pretty explicit:

> You should not force a tag into your title. Because the tags appear
>   below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with
>   the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be
>   able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.
>   Additionally, tags appear on the question page, so other people will
>   take them into account when answering your question.
>
> Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats:
>
> ```
> [tag]: [question title]
> [question title] -- [tag] [tag] [tag]
> [question title] in [tag]
> [tag] [tag] [question title] [tag] [tag] [tag]
> [tag] [tag] [tag] [tag] [tag] [tag] [tag] [tag]
> ```

Yet I constantly see people writing questions such as [*jQuery - Check if element is visible inside iframe in the same domain*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44133048/revisions). This isn't limited to one tag, C#, jQuery, Javascript. I see it a lot and I edit the question to remove the tag **a lot**, to the point where I have a regularly used comment in the edit window.

Being as most "offenders" are relative newbies who (I guess) haven't read the help centre in detail. Can we be more clever here? Prompt the user to not put tags in the question title unless they really have to?

Can we look for the common patterns and prompt the user not to do this?

Should we?

A few random examples:

- [Spotify: How to embed a trackset with the new
  API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090283/spotify-how-to-embed-a-trackset-with-the-new-api)
- [Angular/Ionic - Handling data from multiple JSON Sources in one
  function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132614/angular-ionic-handling-data-from-multiple-json-sources-in-one-function)
- [Jquery - Load Panolens file on Magnific
  popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130938/jquery-load-panolens-file-on-magnific-popup)

Comment: Shouldn't this be titled "[tags]: can/should we stop titles from starting with them?"

Comment: Very meta @JoshCaswell

Comment: I've noticed this problem getting worse and worse recently, with the tag in many cases being simply tacked on to the end of the question, like "Acess object proprty type scirpt". I'd love to do something about it, but can't see any obvious solution.

Comment: It wouldn't fix everything but it seems like this could be fixed by checking to see which tags the question has then alert the user if the title matches (using pseudo back-of-the-napkin regular expressions) `^${tag}.*` or `.* (in)? ${tag}`. It wouldn't catch "Acess object proprty type scirpt" but it would catch a lot of them.

Comment: Before we do this, I think we need to show tags automatically when searching for tumbleweed questions.   I've been guilty of this in the past, but that was only because I would spend my time previously looking at tumbleweed questions and not knowing what language the people where using with out going into the post itself, and I never looked to the front page of stack overflow to find questions to answer, so I just assumed SO always omitted tags being displayed on question titles.  Is there another way to search tumbleweed than this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed

Comment: @snb: There's almost certainly something in SEDE that would do a better job ([tag-specific](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/612083/find-tag-specific-tumbleweed), [general](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/604352/tumbleweed-questions)). In particular, the badge is only ever awarded once, no matter how many times that user asks tumbleweeds.

Comment: @snb SEDE is probably the way to go, but you could also use the advanced search and look for `answers:0 score:0 views:20`. Unfortunately it searches for things with that or _more_, so it doesn't show anything with 19 views. You can tailor that as you see fit, but having it there prevent questions that were _just_ asked from showing. You could search `answers:0 score:0` and jump to page ten or twenty

Comment: I've started telling people why I'm editing their question to try and show user the error of their ways. So whenever I edit the question I now add a comment *"[Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)"*

Comment: Towards the end of the list of formats, I was thinking [spam][spam][spam][spam][lovely][spam].

Comment: @Tas [`answers:0 score:0 views:..20`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+score%3A0+views%3A..20)

Comment: There has already been a lot of previous questions regarding this. [Here is one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70498/146015) I asked almost 7 years ago - but mine talked about *bracketed* tags, which are more likely to be redundant (unbracketed tags do have a small chance of being a legitimate part of the question title). Think of question titles like *C# and the Elvis operator* - your idea would automatically remove the *C#*.

Comment: I don't mean auto remove @slugster. I was thinking more along the lines of a popup, "this question appears to contain a tag please read our guidance on tagging" kind of prompt. Just to point people in the right direction.

Comment: ***Strongly*** related:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309649/1079354

Comment: I just tried to remove tags, but the system told me that a question with the same title already exists (but that question was for a different language) and that I should be more specific.

Comment: I don't think this is big enough a problem to warrant a built-solution. It doesn't hinder the system, and can be fixed with a quick edit from anyone.

Comment: @gre_gor I think that's how the *[question title] in [tag]* version happens in a lot of cases.

Comment: @KevinB "quick edit from anyone" that's the thing, there are almost no anyone and too many questions.

Comment: but... is it causing a real problem? what's the rush?

Comment: @KevinB no, no problem, just that people ain't finding interesting questions to answer or not finding the question that answers their queries, just that.. nothing big.

Comment: Doesn't do any harm having it in there so my opinion is that this is an example of being overly strict on rules

Comment: @AdamCopley that's not rules, that's FAQ style. Remember me where you've seen a faq that doesn't read like sentences.

Comment: @Braiam How are people adding a tag to their title going to not find a question to answer or not find an answer to their question?  We're not talking about instances where those tags are omitted from the question (Because they tend to not be), but rather where they have the tag in the title *as well*.  Having this superfluous text in the title is mildly annoying (and I have no problem fixing it when editing a question), but causes none of those problems.

Comment: @Servy I don't care and you don't either. The questions title should not have forced tags. Point. The system adds it **IF** it is needed, but as general guidance, questions titles should be sentences that describe the question. Tackling the "tagging" problem will move us towards that goal.

Comment: @Braiam So you're saying that you just want to do it for it's own sake, and not because it actually provides any benefit (given that the benefits that you've stated it provides are simply false).

Comment: It's scientific process @Servy, the basis of any decision. You need experimentation as I did. Having a good title prevents new duplicates more often than having several duplicates.

Comment: @Braiam Adding features that don't add value isn't the scientific process... How is not having a redundant word in the title going to prevent duplicate questions?  It won't.  People that are asking duplicate questions are going to do so regardless of whether or not they have the tag in the title.

Comment: @Servy that's,,, what the heck are you talking about right now? I'm talking about how having better titles, prevents duplicates. You are not and frankly, I'm tired of this rodeo. I still support any action that allow us to have any title, at any cost. A feature didn't work, try another. That's a scientific process. Trial and error, you know.

Comment: @Braiam How is removing tags from titles going to prevent duplicates.  You've stated this assertion, but provided no reasoning for why that would be the case.

Comment: @Servy said it twice already, the fact that you are still clueless about that implies that you are not reading my comments, therefore confirming my suspicions why it was so unproductive responding your comments.

Comment: @Braiam No, you haven't described it *at all*.  You've just asserted that magically somehow removing a tag from a title is going to get rid of duplicate questions, you've provided no reasoning whatsoever for why it would do that, and it wouldn't.  People asking duplicate questions are going to do so whether we remove a tag from their title or not.  Making wild unsupported assertions, and then claiming people aren't reading your comments when they ask you to support your assertions, doesn't mean they aren't reading your comments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can we look for the common patterns and prompt the user not to do this?

No, I don't think it's possible to reliably distinguish "good" uses of tags from "bad" ones.

Here's a couple of perfectly reasonable question titles from the front page. I've bolded the tags.

- **ChartJS** not displaying properly in AJAX called page
- **Regular Expression** for String without a “?” character to redirect to string with “?” character
- **MySQL** crashes with “buffer overflow detected” when Spring Boot connects

In all of those cases, the tag name is clearly a part of the question. Recommending to users that they remove those words from the title would make the titles objectively worse, and might discourage them from asking their questions at all.

Comment: Great answer additionally having the tag in the title doesn't do any harm to anyone!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145135/discussion-on-answer-by-duskwuff-can-should-we-stop-questions-from-starting-with).

Answer (score -5):

As I understand it, the advice on tag in titles is not about banning tag from title, but about avoiding to put them forcibly in it, believing it would harm not putting them in.

For me this advice is there for avoiding titles to be bloated by tags, causing them to no more be titles but tags enumeration. Naming one or two technology while still writing a title, not a tag enumeration, sounds right to me.

I even dislike a bit questions where I have to check tags to ascertain for which technology/context the question is, when its title without any technology named in it cause it to be ambiguous. Having the very most relevant information from the title is nice in my opinion, rather than having to scavenge it from several parts.

A little redundancy in human communication never harms, it is just a matter of striking the right balance: not bloating title with many tags or formatting quirks causing it to no more actually be a title (as the advice ask to do), while still providing the most relevant pieces of information for the title to tell what the question is about by itself.

To summarize my viewpoint, as titled there: [Titles should be stand-alone summaries of questions *without* depending on tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180100/titles-should-be-stand-alone-summaries-of-questions-without-depending-on-tags). This question is tagged [title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/title) and [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags). Should it really be stripped out to:

> s should be stand-alone summaries of questions *without* depending on

Or reworded without using neither title word nor tags word?

Edit: I have to clarify a point. I have written "the advice is not about banning tag". Yes the OP did not asked to ban tag words, but instead to put some prompt in place for advising against putting tag words in title. This, overall, will still be harmful I think, because such a prompt would very likely be considered as an almost must and may likely lead to more meaningless titles, especially when seeing them from places where tags are not displayed.

Comment: [Click](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/299295), [click](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/299295)...

Comment: SEO... We are writing content for human, not for SEO. From [Google guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/40349?hl=en) "Provide high-quality content on your pages, especially your homepage. This is the single most important thing to do. " They are smart enough to detect strategy there just for fooling ranking from legit content here for human reasons.

Comment: @Sinatr, your first link still spell it "not have to", which does not mean "must not to". Moreover, from the answer comments: [click](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles#comment930107_130208), and even from [snb comment here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349612/can-should-we-stop-questions-from-starting-with-a-tag?cb=1#comment475745_349612), you can see there are context where we do not have tags at all but only the title. From your second link, there is long list of good title examples which does all contain some tag words!

Comment: Still found from your first link, this other [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180100/titles-should-be-stand-alone-summaries-of-questions-without-depending-on-tags) explain quite well my point of view.

Comment: As example, in your [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43035875/1997232) you don't have to say "Visual Studio 17" in the title. While you can, it doesn't adds to it. "Default reference documentation" - is sufficient, I can see tags when browsing ([picture](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-c0xUck5kDXo/VAmAGvd2oAI/AAAAAAAAalQ/U8A9ykGX-8I/s1600/2014-09-05_11-16-54.png)) and I will anyway look at tags. Tags are important, you shouldn't miss them and once you have them - title doesn't need them.

Comment: Superb, that trouble was very specific to Visual Studio 17 and completely irrelevant to previous versions. As already stated in my previous comments, there are a bunch of contexts where you have no tags displayed, only the title. That not because the main lists display tags that we should ban them from title: many other views does not show them. Like this other question: [Visual studio 2017 code color issue after update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43914872/1178314). Here too, very localized to that specific version, and removing the "tag" from the title just render the title meaningless.

Comment: Completely agreed with this answer, and it is a point that gets lost sometimes. But I think the question is concerned with those cases where the tag is indeed unnecessarily redundant.

Comment: In such case I am totally agreed with manually removing it. But putting in place some intrusive advice about removing them unless really required could lead to more meaningless titles, so I am not for such a change.

Comment: @Liam: "So insead of the title being Jquery - a question it will show as Jquery - jQuery - a question" No, it won't. If the keyword already appears in the title, it won't be added again.